# Database strategies for performance and decreased locking during insert load and reporting?

Tags: sql-server, database

We have a number of places in our system where there are tables logging activity and related info for future processing, then we have reporting dashboards that running queries to pull together stats for a client or across all clients on these tables. Doing everything in the same table often works out fine until it doesn't and there is prolonged locking, often due to daily index fragmentation. In a couple cases we have a stats table that gets updated on some frequency but that is only for broad stats and doesn't account for more fine grained filtering/reporting.

What are the best practices here to allow for performance to be maintained for a database while table size and insert/reporting activity increases?

Comment: Few questions, when you say stats get updated on some frequency, do you mean during operational hours? Are we talking OLTP or OLAP here?

Comment: @mrivanlima As an example we might have a table where activity is inserted and then every 5 minutes a couple stats tables updated with today's stats per client. I believe we are using OLAP.

Comment: If this is an OLAP system, can this stats table wait to be updated later on, when the system is not too busy? When you say stats table, I believe you mean a table created by the developer and not the statistics provided by SQL Server. Another approach I recently took in the company where I work was to create a monitoring script letting me know who was locking my tables so I could act as soon as it happens.I created a blog explaining the details of the script. You can find it here: https://www.misterivanlima.com/who-is-locking-my-processes-a-sql-server-gossip-story/